# What is considered witness data in SegWit?

Tags: transaction-fees, segregated-witness, transaction-weight, witness-data

**What fields in a transaction are considered witness data?** I need this to calculate the `vsize` for fee.

My understanding is these are `marker`, `flag` and `witness` (from [1](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#user-content-Transaction_ID) and [2](https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/#transaction-fee-estimation)).

Or is it just `witness`, without `marker` and `flag`?

Did try to look in source code, but because still new was unsuccessful. Source code references appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is defined in [BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#block-size), section "Block size":

> Blocks are currently limited to 1,000,000 bytes (1MB) total size. We
> change this restriction as follows:
>
> *Block weight* is defined as *Base size* * 3 + *Total size*. (rationale[3])
>
> *Base size* is the block size in bytes with the original transaction
> serialization without any witness-related data, as seen by a
> non-upgraded node.
>
> *Total size* is the block size in bytes with transactions serialized as
> described in BIP144, including base data and witness data.

From this it follows that `marker`, `flag` and `witness` are all considered witness data for weight (and therefore fee) calculation, because these are exactly the fields not present in the original serialization.